# Clojure: Idiomatic Way to Insert a Char in a String

Tags: string, clojure, concatenation

I have a string in Clojure and a character I want to put in between the nth and (n+1)st character.  For example:  Lets say the string is "aple" and I want to insert another "p" between the "p" and the "l".

```
  (prn 
     (some-function "aple" "p" 1 2)) 

  ;; prints "apple" 
  ;; ie "aple" -> "ap" "p" "le" and the concatenated back together.
```

I'm finding this somewhat challenging, so I figure I am missing information about some useful function(s)  Can someone please help me write the "some-function" above that takes a string, another string, a start position and an end position and inserts the second string into the first between the start position and the end position?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

More efficient than using seq functions:

```
(defn str-insert
  "Insert c in string s at index i."
  [s c i]
  (str (subs s 0 i) c (subs s i)))
```

From the REPL:

```
user=> (str-insert "aple" "p" 1)
"apple"
```

NB. This function doesn't actually care about the type of `c`, or its length in the case of a string; `(str-insert "aple" \p 1)` and `(str-insert "ale" "pp" 1)` work also (in general, `(str c)` will be used, which is the empty string if `c` is `nil` and `(.toString c)` otherwise).

Since the question asks for an idiomatic way to perform the task at hand, I will also note that I find it preferable (in terms of "semantic fit" in addition to the performance advantage) to use string-oriented functions when dealing with strings specifically; this includes `subs` and functions from `clojure.string`. See [the design notes at the top of the source of `clojure.string`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.5.1/src/clj/clojure/string.clj) for a discussion of idiomatic string handling.

Comment: By the way, the difference in speed is quite pronounced. A Criterium quick benchmark tells me `(str-insert "aple" "p" 1)` takes about 180 ns, which is 12.5x less than the seq-based version's 2.25 µs.

Comment: Note `subs` wraps Java's `substring` and `str` uses `StringBuilder`. I don't think it is possible to do better.